# Error while training Tensorflow Object Detection model on tensorflow versions 1.14 and 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train Tensorflow Object Detection model. While training when I run the final commands:

For tensorflow version 1.14 :  `python model_main.py --logtostderr --train_dir="/path to dir training/" --pipeline_config_path="Path to ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets_Colab.config"`

For tensorflow version 2.0 :  `python model_main_tf2.py --logtostderr --train_dir="/path to dir training/" --pipeline_config_path="Path to ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets_Colab.config"`

In first case (tensorflow 1.14) I get the following error message: `ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v1 is not supported. See model_builder.py for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow`

and for second (tensorflow 2.0) case I get `ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v1 is not supported. See model_builder.py for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow`

I tried every possible approach but not clear what should I do.
P.S. I am newbie to the deep learning.

Comment: Where did you download your model and can you share your config file? I think you should change the value of the feature extractor in your config file by taking exemple from the model zoo of the Object Detection API : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Tensorflow 1 object detection models.To use them run with tensorflow version **1.15.0**, it should work.These models will not work with tensorflow 2,to use tensorflow 2 models ,use tensorflow version 2.3.0.